# React, mi componente Spinner.jsx no se muestra mientras mi API da una respuesta

Tags: reactjs, spinner, operador-ternario

Hola que tal he hecho una aplicación con React que hace una llamada a una API (buscador de canciones), y la idea es que cuando el usuario ponga el artista y la canción y le de a buscar, aparezca un Spinner y cuando la API traiga los datos, el Spinner se quite.

Mi componente Spinner es el siguiente:

```
import '../styles/Spinner.css'

const Spinner = () => {
  return (
    <div className="spinner">
        <div className="cube1"></div>
        <div className="cube2"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Spinner
```

Lo he tomado de https://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

En mi provider donde tengo la conexión a la API y demás, tengo una variable de estado que se llama cargando, cuando es false, el Spinner no aparece, y cuando es true, aparece, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

Componente `LetrasProvider.jsx`

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const LetrasContext = createContext()
const LetrasProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [alerta, setAlerta] = useState('')
    const [letra, setLetra] = useState('')
    const [cargando, setCargando] = useState(false)
    const busquedaLetra = (busqueda) => {
  
        setCargando(true)
        try {
            const options = {
              method: 'GET',
              url: `https://urlficticia.com/lyrics/${busqueda.cancion}/${busqueda.artista}`,
              headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY}`,
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_HOST}`
                
              }
            };
            axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
              setLetra(response.data.lyrics)
              setAlerta('')
              console.log(response.data.lyrics);
            })
            
        } catch (error) {
            setAlerta('Canción no encontrada')
            setLetra('')
            console.error(error);  
        } 
        setCargando(false)
        
        //
        
    }

    return (
        <LetrasContext.Provider
            value={{
                alerta: alerta,
                setAlerta: setAlerta,
                busquedaLetra,
                letra: letra,
                cargando: cargando
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </LetrasContext.Provider>
    )
}

export {
    LetrasProvider
}

export default LetrasContext
```

El Spinner debe mostrarse en el componente  "principal" `AppLetras.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import useLetras from '../hooks/useLetras'
import Alerta from './Alerta'
import Letra from './Letra'
import Formulario from './Formulario'
import Spinner from './Spinner'

const AppLetras = () => {
    const { alerta, letra, cargando } = useLetras()
  return (
    <>
        <header>
            Búsqueda de letras de canciones
        </header>
        <Formulario />
        <main>
            {alerta ? <Alerta>{alerta}</Alerta> : 
            letra ? <Letra /> : 
            cargando ? <Spinner /> :
             <p className='text-center'>Busca letras de tus artistas favoritos</p>
            }
            
        </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default AppLetras
```

Como veis, me estoy llevando los valores por medio de useContext con un customHook que he hecho, si cargando es true, debería mostrar el Spinner y si no, el texto *Busca letras de tus artistas favoritos*

No sé si tengo el problema en los ternarios, la idea es, si Alerta tiene texto (quiere decir que ha habido un error y salta un mensaje de error), si está vacía pasa a la segunda condición, si letra tiene texto quiere decir que la API ha encontrado la canción y la muestra, mientras letra no tiene texto, tercera condición, aparece el Spinner, en caso contrario si es false aparece el texto que veis.

¿Se os ocurre algo? Un saludo

**Edito** con el código del custom hook:

```
import { useContext } from "react";

import LetrasContext from "../context/LetrasProvider";


const useLetras = () => {
    return useContext(LetrasContext)
}

export default useLetras
```

Comment: Estaría bien ver el código del customHook, igual el problemas está en ese componente.

Comment: Hola @Suso perdón por no contestar antes, lo dejé pendiente y se me pasó, he editado el post con el código del custom hook, aunque yo lo veo todo en orden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es debido a donde estas llamando al `setCargando(false)` fuera de la promesa intenta con esto:

```
    const busquedaLetra = (busqueda) => {
  
    setCargando(true)
    try {
        const options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: `https://urlficticia.com/lyrics/${busqueda.cancion}/${busqueda.artista}`,
          headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY}`,
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_HOST}`
            
          }
        };
        axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
          setLetra(response.data.lyrics)
          setAlerta('')
          console.log(response.data.lyrics);
          setCargando(false)
        })
        
    } catch (error) {
        setAlerta('Canción no encontrada')
        setLetra('')
        console.error(error);
        setCargando(false)  
    } 
    
    //
    
}
```

Presta atención a que llamas a setCargando una vez que el axios finalice el request o cuando haya un error

Comment: Hola que tal, sí eso me soluciona el problema, el spinner ahora se muestra, sin embargo mi API no está funcionando, la consola me devuelve undefinded (la línea 26 de ese mismo archivo), aunque esto ya es otro tema, tengo que ver por qué ahora no me funciona, ni en local ni en producción. Muchas gracias ^^